How do I add a Python script to the enterprise schedule ActiveBatch?
According to the ActiveBatch website, they do support Python scripts:
https://www.advsyscon.com/en-us/activebatch/script-management
But I do not see an option for Python from the script editor in ActiveBatch:

Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.
Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.
Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.
